# What does the participle phrase describe in this sentence?

Tags: participles

I'm trying to describe an event that led someone to think he has been burglarized.

> When he came home, the furniture was moved and the window was slightly
> open, letting in a draft.

My question is, when a sentence has two main clauses ("the furniture was moved" and "the window was slightly open"), is it acceptable to use participle at the end of the sentence ("letting in a draft")?

I wonder if the sentence looks strange, because I am not certain which part "letting in a draft"  is grammatically meant to describe,

> the furniture was moved and the window was slightly open

or

> the window was slightly open.

Comment: The (optional) participial clause ***...letting in a draught*** is fine. The *problem* with your text is that there's a "verb tense dislocation" between *the furniture **was moved*** (essentially a ***verb*** usage) and *the window **was open*** (essentially an ***adjectival*** usage). To resolve this, I think you need *...the furniture **had been** moved...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be understood to apply to *the window was slightly open*, since it's just after that phrase and the furniture having been moved won't let in a draft.

Just by the way, I would use *the furniture had been moved* in that sentence, though *was moved* isn't wrong.

Comment: "I would use the 'furniture had been moved'" -- agreed.  To match, I would also use "the window was slightly opened" or even "the window had been slightly opened".